# GET FILE_ID from Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, google-drive-api

I need, the most simple way to get some sort of object with a list of the FILE_ID's! I do not need a way to automatically grab the unique folder identifier, as I will do that manually. Please, keep it as simple as possible. Here's what I have so far:

```
    var fileID = ["uniquefileid","uniquefileid"];
    var folderID = "uniquefileid";
   document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "<iframe style='position:static; margin-top: -12px; margin-left: -1340px' src='https://drive.google.com/file/d/"+folderID+"_"+fileID[0]+"/preview' width='3480' height='1550' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>";
```

Essentially, uniquefileid is replaced with a number (I don't want to share for obvious reasons), and the folderID will never change.

It seems I also can't $.get() from google either using ajax.Thank's for anyone who can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: so when how do I get the data if I did it a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list), and filter the response to return only fileIds.
Here's the main important part from [JS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js):

```
function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "*"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          console.log(response.result.files);

          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.id);
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

And sure enough it returns a list of IDs.

**Output:**

```
List of File Ids:

1OSZ4e-bHqhagfafdszbhQv_Kn_krjODZYy-S5qy9A
0Bzxcxgk4zccNwI7ekpFbVRzT0pkTkk
0Bxcxzgk4zccNwI7fnpqZnlCcWVwYjQyOUk4Z0VLTdfdfM1JrNjBDNENqRVc0QWs
1cctxcghUdfdlIEL_59hTlJjmSMgvSUKbLpiuJSauoo
1vGx-GEXkrdfdfE0_ynO8Jx2q4BhvQNOImHWzM9CU
1xcxzfjRjdfdfmB3ksuJ0iA4r0KO4GqYrn5ctjr7A
0Bzgk4zccNwI7LXNOQ0xlVU5jTk0
0Bzgk4zccNwIdfdfUWGZXdXc
0Bzgk4zccNwdfdfUpGdmlmVVE
1uDIeJCk4dfdf0S8v82E6h3RhH754
```